# Signing data with javascript why it doesn't work with these keys?

Tags: javascript, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I tested the js tool http://shop-js.sourceforge.net/crypto2.htm mentionned here [Sign data using private key on client-side (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381528/sign-data-using-private-key-on-client-side-javascript)

with a pfx certificate I self created for test I converted to pem but it doesn't work why ? Seems its length is greater than the sample on the site:

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: Is that your real private key/certificate? If yes, go generate new ones, now you've leaked them in public..

Comment: no of course I said it's just generated for test :)